# POST is not defined in RFC 2068 and is not supported by the Servlet API

Tags: rfc

In running Eclipse RAP Application and get Error in firefox 29:

```
HTTP ERROR: 501

Problem accessing /rap. Reason:

    Method false,"ctrlKey":false,"altKey":false}],["set","w1",{"cursorLocation":[630,69]}]]}
GET is not defined in RFC 2068 and is not supported by the Servlet API
```

How can I fix this Error?
Thanks.

Comment: sorry, I've edited the post.

Comment: It says `GET` in your code :) Anyways I'm not able to help you, but I found some very old topic (issues.apache, bug 20850) saying you need to close every request :| Good luck!

Comment: @antidotnet123 were you able to figure out the root cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're constructing wrongly your HTTP request indeed `false,"ctrlKey":false,"altKey":false}],["set","w1",{"cursorLocation":[630,69]}]]}
GET` is not a valid HTTP method

Comment: Can you explain why GET is not a valid HTTP method?
https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Comment: I did not say that `GET` is not a valid HTTP method. I said that `false,"ctrlKey":false,"altKey":false}],["set","w1",{"cursorLocation":[630,69]}]]} GET` is not valid. It looks as if the HTTP client garbled the request big time.